Human error in wave experiment
I am trying to see what the fundamental frequency of a string is by slowly increasing the frequency on a function generator.

This experiment relies on the experimenter to record the frequency as soon as it's visibly obvious that the first harmonic has been reached. However, because it is done just by looking it means that there is some subjectivity which could lead to human error.
I am wondering how to improve my method so that it can limit or improve this. Thank you.

Derive to higher approximation the amplitude v.s. frequency behaviour so that you can plot them, and then curve fit the resonance peak? Note that this will only be helpful if you find a non-human way to read off the amplitude.

Run the sweep up and down. You should get two different frequencies. The average is most likely closer to the correct frequency than either of the two guesses. Slow the sweep down and see how much of a difference you get. Slow sweeps should result in smaller differences than fast ones because human reaction time is less of an error source.

To get a high degree of accuracy in this kind of mechanical experiment you need patience on the order of humans who existed before the digital age. Run the driving for a long time and use video tracking methods with an object of known size to set the scale and watch the peaks in the string until they stabilize and record the deviation from center line, then repeat at increasing frequency. The resonances will be the peaks in amplitude after repeating this across many frequencies. You can do it quick and dirty by judging when you have standing waves or slow and methodical with video tracking, but the amplitude response of a physical string to a driving frequency doesn't lend itself to easy to gather data without some level of human judgement.

However, because it is done just by looking it means that there is some subjectivity which could lead to human error, so do not look at the frequency display whilst altering the frequency and take repeated readings whilst starting below resonance and also above resonance and then take an average.
The system probably has a reasonable large Q-value and so the onset of resonance should be relatively easy to observe.
However with the setup that you have there are other possible sources of error.
The end of the string connected to the vibrator will not be a node and any small change in distance between the retort stand and the vibrator will change the tension in the string.
I would also look at the way the string has been tied at the retort stand end and consider where the node might be and how by moving the knot round a node might be better defined.
A possible improvement is to use two retort stands clamped to the bench with the string tied at each end.
Then tie a vertical thin piece of string onto the vibrator at one end and onto the string under test near a knot at the other end of the thin string and adjust so that the thin string is under slight tension.
